# Command line based tools problems after changing code page on windows 10

Tags: windows, ssh, console, windows-console, codepages

After changing `code page` on my `windows-10` machine, I realized that when I connect to a server via `ssh` through any console (`git-bash`, `windows-cmd`, `power-shell` etc) after typing a few words on the console(when ssh connection is open), the connection will close and I must reconnect again (**Connection reset by IP-Address Port 22**).
The problem is not with the server, as when I connect to the server through other machines everything is OK.
This problem arose when I wanted to type `Persian` characters on the console, so I changed the code page to `65001` using this command on `cmd.exe`

`chcp 65001`

And then I changed the fonts of the console so I could type unicode-8 (Persian) characters later. after that, I changed the `code page` to `1252` and `720` again.
Now when I type `chcp` on the `cmd.exe` it gives `Active code page: 720`.
When I googled the problem I saw that code page `65001` has had some bugs on windows and I think the problem with disconnecting ssh connection on any console is related to changing the code pages.
I don't know how to fix it.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: @Joey By not doing what? I said now I'm on **CP720** but still have the problem. What do you mean of **Documented as unsupported**?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su].

Comment: Thank you @Kenster, I'll do that.So I close the question here.